# Force download and htaccess = zero bytes files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to deny access to a folder on my server, in which there are files that can only be downloaded via a php script. 
The php script is used to force the download of files, just like that:

```
  function downloadFile($file){
        $file_name = $file;
        $mime = 'application/force-download';
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Cache-Control: private',false);
        header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));    // provide file size
        header('Connection: close');
        readfile($file_name);
        exit();
    }
```

And the htaccess must provide access only to localhost:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

But every time the script download a zero bytes files with the same name, instead of the complete file. When I delete htaccess, however, everything is fine.. I can't figure out where is the error.
Thanks for your help

Comment: What are the permissions on the file and directory that readfile() is trying to read?  Keep in mind that the web server has to have access to it.  So if your web server is running as user httpd, for example, then httpd has to have read access to the file.  You can test this by running something like sudo -u httpd cat /path/to/file.

Comment: Thanks @jedwards, setting $file as an absolute path has fixed the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that readfile(); need the absolute path of the file on the machine rather than a url.

e.g. /home/person/file.exe